# Are the Dragon names based on anything?

Tags: fairy-tail

Just some random curiosity about the Dragons in *Fairy Tail*.

- Acnologia,
  Igneel,
  Grandeeney,
  Weisslogia,
  Metalicana,
  Skiadrum,
  Atlas Flame,
  Zirconis,
  Motherglare,
  Scissor Runner,
  Revire,
  Dark Dragon,
  Rock Dragon

Are their names based on anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems some of their names have parts which relate to their nature:

- **Weisslogia**: Weiss or Weiß is German for "white". Sting performs White Dragon Slayer to produce beams of sacred light, so we can see how White factors into Weisslogia's name.
- **Metalicana**: Obviously, the use of Metal in its name reflects the Iron Dragon Slayer Magic Gajeel uses
- **Skiadrum**: Skia or "σκιά" is Greek for shadow, and Skiadrum is the Shadow Dragon.
- **Atlas Flame**: Atlas is the name of a Greek god, but I do not know how it would relate to the character. Images I have seen of this dragon show that it's totally wrapped in flames, and its title is also the Flame Dragon
- **Motherglare**: This may be related to its [Egg Magic](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Egg_Magic). In most cases, mothers use a form of egg to give birth to children. In a lot of fictional works, Dragons lay eggs to give birth.
- **Scissor Runner**: May be a reference to the two huge spines coming out of the top of its head and its chin
- **Rock/Dark Dragons**: Obviously for their appearance. However, those aren't their names, but how they are referred to due to their appearance.
- (**Revire** has a somewhat aquatic appearance, and its name is pronounced as "Rivaia", which kinda sounds like river. However, that is a long shot.)
- **Igneel** In Latin the word Igne means fire which reflects the fact that he is the fire dragon king.
- **Acnologia** : "Acno" is a Greek word used to reference aging. The word "Logia" is a Greek word that translates roughly as "sayings, utterances, oracles". Thus you could interpret his name as the Ender of Eras or The Prophet of the End.

**Grandeeney** In Japanese Grandeeney’s name is Grandine, which is a Italian word that means "hail."

I should point out that I have not read the manga nor watched enough of the anime (I have seen like 50 episodes), and I found out all of these by google searching for images, picking apart their names and looking up Wikipedia articles. Someone else may have a more accurate answer. These are just my observations and may help others fill in holes in their own research.

Comment: I like your answer, my main curiousity came from Igneel thou. Made me think of Ignite. Dragon was indeed a typo and I removed it from the list ;)

Comment: @Dimitrimx you have a point there with Igneel however that's kinda like what i said about Revire, however who know maybe the writers thought the exact same thing but i'm not a mind reader

Comment: バイスロギア (Weisslogia) as the furigana to 白竜 (White Dragon), スキアドラム (Skiadrum) as the furigana to 影竜 (Shadow Dragon).

Answer (score 7):

To add to the list,

**Igneel**: most likely derived from Ignis, which means fire.

**Grandeeney**: She's the skydragon, named Grandine in Japanese. This translates to *hail* from Italian, which might explain the relationship

**Acnologia**: "Acno" is a Greek word used to reference aging. The word "Logia" is a Greek word from New Testament scholarship that translates roughly as "sayings, utterances, oracles". His name could thus be translated as "The Prophet of The End," as well as "Ender of Eras"

Answer (score 5):

I believe **Igneel** comes from [igneous rock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igneous_rock), which refers to rocks formed through the cooling and solidification of magma or lava.

The other two kinds of rocks are sedimentary and metamorphic. Sedimentary rocks form from once-living things (examples are fossils and coal). Metamorphic rocks are igneous rocks that were reheated after they were formed.

Therefore, seeing as igneous rocks are the only ones formed by magma/lava, that's where I figured it came from.

The name probably also comes from "ignite", but I might be overthinking about it.

Source(s): Science teacher