# How many Dragons are there in total in Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

Some of the Dragon Slayers were trained by Dragons, while others gained Dragon Slayer Magic by means of Lacrima implants (as in the case of Laxus). For Lacrima implants, the Dragon Slayer Magic has to be extracted from a Dragon (that's my assumption). So how many Dragons in total, living or dead, exist in Fairy Tail? If possible please provide their names.

Comment: 13 dragons were named in the series (5 dragons that raised humans from the current time line, Acnologia and the 7 dragons that came through the Eclipse Gate). 400 years ago, there were thousands or maybe millions of dragons, but they got extinct.

Comment: I mentioned the 13 named ones in my question [Are the dragon names based on anything](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/are-the-dragon-names-based-on-anything)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Fairy Tail [wiki](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon#Known_Dragons), there are **18 Dragons** who have been given a name.

> However in the [Grand Magic Games](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Magic_Games_arc) arc we learn that 400 years ago the world was ruled by dragons. Many a Dragon were slain, and thus, the humans became known as Dragon Slayers.

**Dragons with titles:**

- [Igneel](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Igneel) - The Fire Dragon King
- [Metalicana](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Metalicana) - The Iron Dragon
- [Grandeeney](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Grandeeney) - The Sky Dragon
- [Acnologia](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Acnologia) - The Black Dragon (The Black Dragon of the Apocalypse)
- [Weisslogia](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Weisslogia) - The White Dragon
- [Skiadrum](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Skiadrum) - The Shadow Dragon
- [Zirconis](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Zirconis) - The Jade Dragon
- [Atlas Flame](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Atlas_Flame) - The Fire Dragon
- [Belserion](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Belserion) - The Sage Dragon
- [Irene Belserion](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Irene_Belserion) - Queen of Dragons
- [Elefseria](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Elefseria) - The Law Dragon
- [Mercuphobia](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Mercuphobia) - The Water God Dragon

**Other named Dragons:**

- [Motherglare](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Motherglare)
- [Scissor Runner](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Scissor_Runner)
- [Levia](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Levia)
- [Dark Dragon](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Dragon)
- [Rock Dragon](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Rock_Dragon)
- [Animus](https://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Animus)

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands, but the main ones (that trained the dragon slayers) are of a number of 5. (**Igneel** (Natsu), **Grandine** (Wendy), **Metallicana** (Gajeel),  **Skiadrum** (Rogue) and **Weisslogia** (Sting).) There is also **Acnologia**, making a total of 6 main dragons. There are a lot of other ones, but these are the dragons worth remembering. Especially Acnologia. There are other minor ones, but I don't think they are really important to the plot. The number of names mentioned is of 13, though.

Comment: Pretty sure it was "Igneel" instead of "Ignir".

Comment: My bad. Ignir is the french/japanese way of saying it.

Comment: @Alagaros If you think someone made a spelling mistake, it is allowed and encouraged to edit the post yourself instead of commenting :)

Answer (score 0):

there are several dragon slayers (if u look at the dragon war era), but the ones that actually played a role in the story are:

- Natsu (Fairy Tail)
- Gajeel (Fairy Tail)
- Wendy (Fairy Tail)
- Sting (Sabertooth)
- Rogue (Sabertooth)
- Laxus (Fairy Tail)(Lacrima)
- Eric (General Cobra)(Crime Sorcery)(Lacrima)
- Irene (Erza's mother)(Spriggan 12)
- Acnologia (Dragon King)
- God Serena (Wizard Saint)(Spriggan 12)(Strongest Man on Ishgar)

That makes a total of 10 dragon slayers

Answer (score -2):

There are 18 dragons:

- Igneel
- Metalicana
- Grandeeney
- Acnologia
- Weisslogia
- Skiadrum
- Ziroconis
- Atlas Flame
- Motherglare
- Scissor runner
- Levia
- Dark Dragon
- Rock Dragon
- Belsrion
- Irene Belserion
- Animus
- Elefseria
- Mercuphobie